# For different route, same react component does not get mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having an issue when using same component for two different routes, where i am expecting that that component gets destroyed and than get mounted again, but that does not happen:

When i change from `/page1` to `/page2` by clicking on the button **Change to /page2** output in the console should be:

```
COMPONENT DISMOUNTED
COMPONENT MOUNTED
```

This means that `MyComponent` should be destroyed after path changes. This is important because i rely on the fact that change of the path gives me fresh component. I don't want to reset states and other hooks to default values manually.
[Codesadnbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/same-component-different-routes-problem-6xwvr?file=/src/App.tsx)

Is there a React problem or perhaps React router one?

**App component**

```js
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter,
  Navigate
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* Routes */}
      <Routes>
        {/* Route 1 */}
        <Route path="/page1" element={<MyComponent someProp="value1" />} />
        {/* Route 2 */}
        <Route path="/page2" element={<MyComponent someProp="value2" />} />

        <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to={{ pathname: '/page1' }} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

**MyComponent**

```js
import type { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  useNavigate
} from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<{ someProp: string }> = ({ someProp }) => {
  const history = useNavigate();

  const onRouteChange = (route: string) => {
    history(route);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('COMPONENT MOUNTED');

    return () => {
      console.log('COMPONENT DISMOUNTED');
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => onRouteChange('/page1')}>Change to /page1</button>
      <button onClick={() => onRouteChange('/page2')}>Change to /page2</button>

      <div>{someProp}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React is actually doing its job correctly, since `Route` component returns same component with changed prop `someProp`. In any other case where i have a component where i change prop to it, this would happen again.

There is no obvious way to find this out unless you stumble upon this problem. Although thinking in the way React works, this should be obvious.

**SOLUTION**
Simple `key` should be added to both `MyComponent` components. In this way, React will know, because of the different `key`, that new component returned by `Route` differs.
[Codesandbox to the solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/same-component-different-routes-problem-solution-3cyms?file=/src/App.tsx)

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* Routes */}
      <Routes>
        {/* Route 1 */}
        <Route
          path="/page1"
          element={<MyComponent key="/page1" someProp="value1" />}
        />
        {/* Route 2 */}
        <Route
          path="/page2"
          element={<MyComponent key="/page2" someProp="value2" />}
        />

        <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to={{ pathname: "/page1" }} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: Also the solution I would have suggested.